# how to set the different color cell by cell in excel using java

Tags: java

```
for(int j=0;j<maxIncrementalLayer;j++){ 

        switch(j){

        case 0:{
            style.setFillBackgroundColor(IndexedColors.SKY_BLUE.getIndex());
            break;
        }
        case 1:{
            style.setFillBackgroundColor(IndexedColors.DARK_GREEN.getIndex());
            break;
        }
        case 2:{
            style.setFillBackgroundColor(IndexedColors.LIGHT_YELLOW.getIndex());
            break;
        }

        }
```

in maxIncrementalLayer will get some number, till that number need to set the different color for each cell
if we get more than 20 , need to set the different colors after for that cells

```
private void writeHeader(int maxIncrementalLayer, XSSFRow row, CellStyle style) { 
    int i=0, k=0; 
    for(int j=0;j<maxIncrementalLayer;j++){ 
        switch(j){ 
        case 0:{ 
            style.setFillBackgroundColor(IndexedColors.SKY_BLUE.getIndex‌​()); 
            break; 
            }
        row.createCell(i++).setCellValue("AAA"); 
        row.getCell(k++).setCellStyle(style); 
        row.createCell(i++).setCellValue("BBB"); 
        row.getCell(k++).setCellStyle(style); 
        row.createCell(i++).setCellValue("CCC"); 
        row.getCell(k++).setCellStyle(style); 
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: What library are you using to manipulate the excel file? Apache POI? JXCell?

Comment: can you share some more code or edit the question, so that we can understand

Comment: i am using Apache POI,

Comment: private void writeHeader(int maxIncrementalLayer, XSSFRow row, CellStyle style) {
  int i=0, k=0;
for(int j=0;j<maxIncrementalLayer;j++){
switch(j){
    case 0:{
       style.setFillBackgroundColor(IndexedColors.SKY_BLUE.getIndex());
        break;
    }row.createCell(i++).setCellValue("AAA");
   row.getCell(k++).setCellStyle(style);
   row.createCell(i++).setCellValue("BBB");
   row.getCell(k++).setCellStyle(style);
   row.createCell(i++).setCellValue("CCC");
   row.getCell(k++).setCellStyle(style);

}

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] headers = new String[] { "AA","BB","CC" };     
    int i=0,k=0,m=0;
        for(int j=0;j<maxIncrementalLayer;j++){
            m++;
            if(m==1){
                CellStyle style = template.createCellStyle();
                style.setFont(font);
                style.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
                style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.GOLD.getIndex());
                style.setFillBackgroundColor(new HSSFColor.GOLD().getIndex());

                for (int rn = 0; rn < headers.length; rn++) {
                    row.createCell(i++).setCellValue(headers[rn]);
                    row.getCell(k++).setCellStyle(style);
              }
            }else if(m==2){
                CellStyle style1 = template.createCellStyle();
                style1.setFont(font);
                style1.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
                style1.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.LIGHT_BLUE.getIndex());
                style1.setFillBackgroundColor(new HSSFColor.LIGHT_BLUE().getIndex());
                for (int rn = 0; rn < headers.length; rn++) {

                    row.createCell(i++).setCellValue(headers[rn]);
                    row.getCell(k++).setCellStyle(style1);
              }
            }else if(m==3){
                CellStyle style2 = template.createCellStyle();
                style2.setFont(font);
                style2.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);              style2.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.LIGHT_GREEN.getIndex());
                style2.setFillBackgroundColor(new HSSFColor.LIGHT_GREEN().getIndex());
                for (int rn = 0; rn < headers.length; rn++) {
                    row.createCell(i++).setCellValue(headers[rn]);
                    row.getCell(k++).setCellStyle(style2);
              }
     m=0;
    }

we need to create for each color one CellStyle object
```